Confused about walks notation
The author writes the following in the article

Proof. Let $p':a\rightarrow b$ and $q':b\rightarrow a$ be walks. Then $p'pq',p'qq':b\rightarrow b$ are closed walks...

Then the rest of the proof does not clarify anything about how the walks $p'pq'$ and $p'qq'$ are closed at $b$. I am having trouble understading how these walks start at vertex $b$ and end at vertex $b$. Wouldn't it be the case that $p'pq',p'qq':a\rightarrow a$ because we start from vertex $a$ in $p'$ and finish at vertex $a$ in $q'$.
Or could it mean that both $p'pq'$ and $p'qq'$ contain a sub-walk closed in vertex $b$?

Check the notational conventions of the paper; it looks like paths are being concatenated from right to left.  Thus $p'pq'$ means $q'$, then $p$, then $p'$ which indeed yields a walk from $b$ to $b$, and similarly for $p'qq'$.

that makes sense
